# How do you align images to the side of text with html and css?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website for one of my college classes and we're just getting to the sort of styling section of the course and I can't figure out how to align images to the side of things like blocks of text or other images.

For example

```css
p.boxed {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 725px;
  margin-left: 275px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

p.image1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 275px;
  margin-left: 725px;
}
```

```html
<p class="boxed"> placehooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolder text </p>
<p class="image1"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg/330px-Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg" alt="Orchid performing in 2000">
</p>
```

how would I align the image to the right of the text

Comment: Could you use StackOverflow's "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" feature if possible? It's the 7th option in the editing bar. It makes a "Run code snippet" button, by which we can easily view what your code currently does.

Answer (score 0):

by adding the image to a  element, you can change the alignment of it to allow for different positionings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To align the image to the right of the text, you can put both elements in the same container and use CSS Flexbox with the container set to display: flex; and justify-content: space-between;, allows the text and image to be automatically aligned with the text on the left and the image on the right.

```
 <div class="container">
<p class="boxed"> placehooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo 
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolder
text </p>
<p class="image1"> 
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg/330px-Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg" alt="Orchid performing in 2000">
</p>
</div>


.container {
display: flex;
}

   .boxed {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  }

  .image1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Add some margin between text and image */
 }

.image1 img {
 max-width: 100%; /* Ensure image doesn't exceed its container width */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To align images to the side of text or other elements, you can use CSS to float the image to the left or right, and adjust margins as necessary. Here's how you can modify your HTML and CSS:

```css
p.boxed {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

p.image1 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="boxed"> placehooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolder text </p>
<p class="image1"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg/330px-Orchid_-_Stierch.jpg" alt="Orchid performing in 2000">
</p>
```